# Odoo Prevent Selected Duplicate Record in One2many Field

Tags: odoo, erp, odoo-14

I want to prevent the selected record to show again in the combo box.

[image]

As you can see, the `710 - Maleo` show again after I selected that record before.

Field declaration for `One2many` field

```
class RMReservationOrderLine(models.Model):
    _name = "rm.reservation.order.line"
    _description = "Reservation Order Line"

    room_line_ids = fields.One2many('rm.reservation.room.line', 'order_id', string='Rooms')
```

Model class for `One2many` field

```
class RMReservationRoomLine(models.Model):
    _name = "rm.reservation.room.line"
    _description = "Reservation Room Line"

    order_id = fields.Many2one('rm.reservation.order.line', string='Order', required=True, ondelete='cascade')
    room_id = fields.Many2one('rm.room', string='Room', required=True)
```

**UPDATE**

Since my model class for the `One2many` field just have a single field, `room_id`, I just change the `One2many` field to `Many2many`. Because by default `Many2many` field prevent duplicate record.

[image]

But I still want to know how to prevent duplicate records if I use the `One2many` field, In case I have more than 1 field in the model class for `One2many`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the same case as you want.

I already modified the Sales Order, so when the product in the sales order line it's already selected then the product will not be shown again in the selected product.

I used odoo-14 and inherited the sales.order.line and modified the function product_id_change() to become:

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def product_id_change(self):
    values = super(SaleOrderLine, self).product_id_change()
    filter_product_ids = [data.product_id.id for data in self.order_id.order_line]
    if values is None:
        values = {}
    values['domain'] = {'product_id' : [('id', 'not in', filter_product_ids)]}
    return values
```